# How to start an activity with custom values

Tags: android, .net, android-activity

Hey guys I am reasonably new to Android programming but have some experience with .net anyway what I would like to do is create a class say `RestartDialog` then call this class from an activity. Normally in .net I would use:

```
RestartDialog rd = new RestartDialog();

rd.setType(EXTENDED_TYPE);
rd.show;
```

then it would start in extended mode however in Android you need Intents to start activitys and this is the only way am I right? I know I can use `Intent.putExtra` etc but I will need to set many values first.

What would be my best bet to achive this please? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent is the way to send data. so in case you have to send many data, you can use `Parcelable`. It is way faster also..

If you're just passing objects around then `Parcelable` was designed for this. It requires a little more effort to use than using Java's native serialization, but it's way faster (and I mean way, WAY faster).

From the docs, a simple example for how to implement is:

```
// simple class that just has one member property as an example
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private int mData;

    /* everything below here is for implementing Parcelable */

    // 99.9% of the time you can just ignore this
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(mData);
    }

    // this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyParcelable(in);
        }

        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    };

    // example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
    private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
        mData = in.readInt();
    }
}

Observe that in the case you have more than one field to retrieve from a given Parcel, you must do this in the same order you put them in (that is, in a FIFO approach).

Once you have your objects implement Parcelable it's just a matter of putting them into your Intents with putExtra():
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("name_of_extra", myParcelableObject);

Then you can pull them back out with getParcelableExtra():
Intent i = getIntent();
MyParcelable myParcelableObject = (MyParcelable) i.getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");
```

You may also use GSON to send data..

Comment: Thank you mate I will look in to Parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to create an `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

Think of an intent as a way to store data values:

```
intent.putExtra("type", EXTENDED_TYPE);
```

When you're done putting information in your intent, you start the activity:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your new activity, you extract the values you need in your onCreate method:

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_login_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    this.type = intent.getIntExtra("type", 0);
```

In this case, I've made getIntExtra return `0` if the extra "type" was not set.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Though the easiest solution would be:

To create a class with static data members with getters setters.

set from one activity and get from another activity that object.

activity A
mytestclass.staticfunctionSet("","",""..etc.);

activity b
mytestclass obj= mytestclass.staticfunctionGet();

Comment: This seem like a easy solution too thanks.